# How to create a new element on cursor DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How would I be able to create a new element and have it placed right where the mouse/cursor is located?
I have some example code below:

```
<div id = "adivthing></div>

<script>
var newthing = document.createElement("input");                
document.getElementById("adivthing").appendChild(newthing); 
</script>
```

Comment: Give the new element `position: absolute` style and then set the `left` and `top` styles to the cursor location.

Comment: Okay I'll get right to this! I might come back for more questions.

Comment: Might also append it to body, otherwise it might not work if the elements parent is positioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use either the `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` style properties on the `newthing` element, you can then use the `left` and `top` properties to move the element around the box.

If you get the mouse coordinates from your triggering event (e.g. click), you can add the appropriate `left` and `top` to your element.

Example below:

```js
function createInput(event){
  var newthing = document.createElement("input");                
  document.getElementById("adivthing").appendChild(newthing); // Your existing code


  // get the coordinates of the mouse
  var x = event.clientX;     // get the horizontal coordinate
  var y = event.clientY;   // get the vertical coordinate

  // position newthing using the coordinates
  newthing.style.position = "fixed"; // fixes el relative to page. Could use absolute.
  newthing.style.left = x + "px";
  newthing.style.top = y + "px";
}
```

```css
/* Optional - Making new things more obvious in the pen */
input{
    height: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    background: red;
}

#adivthing{
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- Onclick event added to your existing markup -->
<div id="adivthing" onclick="createInput(event)"></div>
```

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as Barmar has provided. Also, as ritaj states, you will need an ancestor of newthing to be set to position: relative in order to use position: absolute on newthing.